# What's the best way to backup simple text data to Google Drive or Dropbox or any other free cloud service using JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cordova, phonegap

I am looking for a way to backup/store simple text data to a free online cloud service. Basically, I want to take a backup of a user's localStorage object to either my personal account on a free cloud service or onto the user's account. I want to do this as simply as possible and security is not much of an issue. I want to use plain JS or jQuery (or any other JS solution) and incorporate it into my existing **PhoneGap** application.

What i want:

1. take periodic backups of localStorage object to any cloud service using JS.
2. restore data from these backups whenever required (or whenever the app is launched)
3. do this as simply and quickly as possible

Answer (score -1):

There are a million and one way to accomplish this. So here is the one I would go with. Use [Google Firebase](https://firebase.google.com)(BaaS), it has extremely simple setup, you could probably get this done in 50 lines of JS code. It has pretty good free tier.

Comment: Thanks @somerandomusername. I'll check it out and mark this as correct solution if it works for me.